# How can I change this while loop to a for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Here I have a `while` loop in java code: could you please tell me how can I change it to a `for` loop.

I know the condition is `rentalIterator.hasNext()`, then do the `while` loop. But I can't figure out how can I convert it to a `for` loop.

It doesn't show the number of iterations. But in class rental there are 3 cases. 
Does that means the iteratation for it is 3?

```
    public double daysRented(double charge, Rental rental) {
        switch (rental.getMovie().getPriceCode()) {
            case Movie.REGULAR:
                charge += 2;
                if (rental.getDaysRented() > 2)
                    charge += (rental.getDaysRented() - 2) * 1.5;
                break;
            case Movie.NEW_RELEASE:
                charge += rental.getDaysRented() * 3;
                break;
            case Movie.CHILDRENS:
                charge += 1.5;
                if (rental.getDaysRented() > 3)
                    charge += (rental.getDaysRented() - 3) * 1.5;
               break;
         }
         return charge;
    }
    while (rentalIterator.hasNext()) {
        double charge = 0;
        Rental rental = (Rental) rentalIterator.next();
        frequentRenterPoints = rental.frequentRenterPoints(frequentRenterPoints, rental) 
        result += rental.getDaysRented() + " days of '" + rental.getMovie().getTitle() + "' $" + String.valueOf(charge) + "\n";
        totalAmount += charge;
    }
```

Comment: Since you don't show any information about `rentalInterator` it's not really clear what you're asking. It might help you to read up on the concept [mcve] in the site's [help].

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 for (Rental rental = (Rental) rentalIterator.next(); rentalIterator.hasNext(); )
            double charge = 0;
            frequentRenterPoints = 
            rental.frequentRenterPoints(frequentRenterPoints, rental) 
            result += rental.getDaysRented() +
            " days of '" + rental.getMovie().getTitle() +
            "' $" + String.valueOf(charge) + "\n";
            totalAmount += charge;
        }
```

Comment: Why would you even declare `x` if you don't need it in the loop?

Comment: Yes your right, there was no need for me to declare it there. I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks guys I understand. This is a loop for the iterator. So, we just put the definition and the condition into the for loop condition. Sorry for the incomplete code that I forgot to add

```
Iterator rentalIterator = rentals.iterator();
```

so here we have the answer:

```
for (Iterator rentalIterator = rentals.iterator();rentalIterator.hasNext();) {
    double charge = 0;

    Rental rental = (Rental) rentalIterator.next();

    charge = rental.charge(charge, rental);

    frequentRenterPoints = rental.frequentRenterPoints(frequentRenterPoints, rental);

    result += rental.getDaysRented() +
    " days of '" + rental.getMovie().getTitle() +
    "' $" + String.valueOf(charge) + "\n";
    totalAmount += charge;
}
```

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more descriptive here, one of basic difference between a `while` and a `for` loop is that `while` uses a *condition* for iteration where as `for` uses a statement. The format of statement is generally `for(initialization;condition;iteration)` in which both initialization and iteration are optional.

Coming back to your question, there are several ways to convert the while loop into a for loop(as mentioned in the above comments) and one of the simplest would be to just put *condition* being used for the `while` loop in `for` loop in the format `for(;condition;)``, which in your case would be something like:

```
for(;rentalIterator.hasNext();){
    //your code
}
```